# Create time table view from schedule data

Tags: mysql, database-design, pivot

Currently I am developing a time table program using Codeigniter framework in `PHP` and `MySQL`. I have the `schedule` table having the following data:

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------+
| Schedule ID | Subject Name | Day       | Period |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------+
| 1           | Biology      | Monday    | 1      |
| 2           | Biology      | Wednesday | 2      |
| 3           | Biology      | Friday    | 3      |
| 4           | Physics      | Tuesday   | 8      |
| 5           | Physics      | Thursday  | 6      |
| 6           | Math         | Monday    | 7      |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------+
```

I can take each row of the `schedule` table as array. I want to create a time table in the following view (using `HTML` table):

```
+---+---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
| # | Monday  | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday  |
+---+---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
| 1 | Biology |         |           |          |         |
+---+---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
| 2 |         |         | Biology   |          |         |
+---+---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
| 3 |         |         |           |          | Biology |
+---+---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
| 4 |         |         |           |          |         |
+---+---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
| 5 |         |         |           |          |         |
+---+---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
| 6 |         |         |           | Physics  |         |
+---+---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
| 7 | Math    |         |           |          |         |
+---+---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
| 8 |         | Physics |           |          |         |
+---+---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
```

I would appreciate any help regarding to create the table in above format.

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far? Any PHP code will be helpful for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT ScheduleID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Day = 'Monday' THEN SubjectName END) AS Monday,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Day = 'Tuesday' THEN SubjectName END) AS Tuesday,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Day = 'Wednesday' THEN SubjectName END) AS Wednesday,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Day = 'Thursday' THEN SubjectName END) AS Thursday,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Day = 'Friday' THEN SubjectName END) AS Friday
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ScheduleID
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d48a5/3)

**Edit:**

You seem to want to group by `Period` instead of `ScheduleID`. You can create an in-line table that holds all possible `Period` values, or use a look up table if you already have one:

```sql
SELECT t1.Period,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Day = 'Monday' THEN SubjectName END) AS Monday,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Day = 'Tuesday' THEN SubjectName END) AS Tuesday,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Day = 'Wednesday' THEN SubjectName END) AS Wednesday,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Day = 'Thursday' THEN SubjectName END) AS Thursday,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Day = 'Friday' THEN SubjectName END) AS Friday 
FROM (SELECT 1 AS Period UNION ALL 
      SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 6 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 7 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 8) AS t1
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.Period = t2.Period
GROUP BY t1.Period
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d48a5/4)

Comment: @Giorgos I really liked your approach but please check 4th and 5th rows. Since you're not checking *period* column, your result different than expected by danishjo .

Comment: @TuğcaEker ?Yes, you are right. I noticed the issue only after I had posted my answer. He has to tweak the query a little bit to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @Giorgos In my humble opinion, achieving the expected result is not an easy task for SQL. But I'm very curious about your solution. Can you share the solution in your mind? I'll be very appreciated.

Comment: Seeing as you're spitting the whole thing out to PHP anyway, this is an unnecessary (and potentially limiting) intermediate step.

Comment: @Strawberry There are multiple solutions for that but since the owner of the question does not provide any PHP code we couldn't do it in PHP (Your downvote is poinless).

Comment: Thank you @TuğcaEker . I really wondering the PHP solution. I tried to keep in a 2D array and compare with the result coming from database. But, it did not work.

Comment: @danishjo share some code if you want to get an answer.

Comment: @TuğcaEker The OP didn't provide any MySQL code either, but that didn't seem to stop GB.